# JSON array data return Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

am having the data sa

```
var data = '[{"idcoupons_tbl":"1","discount_percent":"10"}]';
```

when i try to parse and get a `discount_percent` ie

```
var result= jQuery.parseJSON(data); 
alert(result["discount_percent"]);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1pbvjwdz/)
   it returns Undifined, thanks in advance

Comment: `result[0]["discount_percent"]`, it's an array

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp alexeys answer works result[0].discount_percent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your variable `result` is an array, currently with 1 item, doing

```
result[0]["discount_percent"]
```

should work

Answer (score 3):

As result is an array you need to use index.

```
result[0]["discount_percent"]
```

[DEMO](http://10)

Answer (score 3):

```
var data = '[{"idcoupons_tbl":"1","discount_percent":"10"}]';  
var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data); 

alert(result[0].discount_percent);
```